# Make ImageView appear like in Safari Top Sies

Tags: iphone, ios

You may have seen that images are placed in a curved screen when we open Safari browser and click on Net Tab. It is listed under top sites. So my question is I have a UIImageview and I need to make that image view curved like in Safari. How can I do that? Can I do it using QuartzCore? Please help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. All you need is to do a research in CATransform3D from QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h. 
You will be able to scale/rotate/perspective your images as you wish, to give them the same form of Safari to sites view. Unfortunately the implementation is up to you, it's a huge work.

Just not to let you "alone in the dark", here is a perspective of an image:

```
UIView *myView = (UIView*)instance_to_your_UIImageView;
    CALayer *layer = myView.layer;
    CATransform3D rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    rotationAndPerspectiveTransform.m14 = 1.0 / 500;
    rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    layer.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTransform;
```

Below is a "before" and "after":

[image: BEFORE]
[image: AFTER]

Cheers!